# How to remove the C++ 11 extension warning in the vsCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When i use the `auto` type, there just have a warning in my vscode

```
'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] (14, 10)
```

So how can i remove this warning

Comment: Use c++11 flag (or higher) ? Before, I doubt you actually want to use the old `auto`.

Comment: You remove it by enabling C++11. Consult the documentation for your compiler and for VSCode to learn how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to edit the `c_cpp_properties.json` file. See an example of it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).

```
{
  "env": {
    "myDefaultIncludePath": ["${workspaceFolder}", "${workspaceFolder}/include"],
    "myCompilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-7"
  },
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "includePath": ["${myDefaultIncludePath}", "/another/path"],
      "macFrameworkPath": ["/System/Library/Frameworks"],
      "defines": ["FOO", "BAR=100"],
      "forcedInclude": ["${workspaceFolder}/include/config.h"],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "compileCommands": "/path/to/compile_commands.json",
      "browse": {
        "path": ["${workspaceFolder}"],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

In that file an option `cppStandard`  is listed. It has to be set to `c++11`. Then `auto` will be supported.

Comment: I've tried this solution and it doesn't appear to be working for me on MacOS. I've also tried changing the C++ standard through VSCode settings along with setting C++20 as the standard across numerous json settings files.